# Return Boolean mask of columns that contain a string

Tags: python, pandas, select, match

I have a Pandas Dataframe with say 5 columns. Some of the columns contain a string "aa". I want to return a list containing booleans that identify the columns that contain "XX"
Example

```
     cl1  cl2  cl3  cl4  cl5  
1.   ds   fr   we   iu   XX     
2.   sx   XX   ee   ee   nn
3.   df   vd   rr   we   mm
4.   er   we   gf   wq   hh
```

The result should be

```
res= [False True False False True]
```

I tried with str.contain of str.match but this only apply to Series and I don't want to iterate over the Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so:

```
res = (df == 'XX').any(0).tolist()
```

Comment: this works but on the PyCharm IDE I got this warning: "unresolved attribute reference 'any' for class 'bool'" Is it possible to get rid of this warning?

Comment: if you want to remove the warning, you can do so: `import warnings`
`warnings.simplefilter('ignore')`